# google ajax-search-api call "quota exceeded" on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-ajax-search-api

i tried to use the custom search api ( http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/websearch/docs ) with java. it works perfectly on eclipse on my local machine.

when i try to do the same from google app engine the reply is: {"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Quota Exceeded.  Please see http://code.google.com/apis/websearch", "responseStatus": 403}

i do not understand. isn't it possible to call search api from GAE apps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the very top of that page you linked to, they note that the API has been deprecated and the number of search queries you can make is limited.

However, if you absolutely NEED to use that API instead of the Custom Search API as Google suggests, there are a few troubleshooting steps you can take:

1) Check that your API key is unique to the project, and the limited number of queries you're allowed isn't being consumed by some other application.

2) Google does (did?) hostname filtering so that one computer doesn't use up all the API requests. You may be able to move the queries to Javascript instead of Java -- essentially move the request from the server to the client.

3) Try using a named backend ([Java Backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends.html))